# Why am I getting java.lang.ClassCastException on checkbox.getTag()?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Can you tell me why my code isn't working? It used to be working fine and now that I'm changing over from `listView` to `recyclerView` I'm getting:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to com.app.SelectPhoneContact
```

Whichever checkboxes are in my `recyclerView`, it's supposed to `toast` the corresponding numbers of those ones that are checked.

```
 Button btnGetItem = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGetItem);
        btnGetItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //loop through the Matching Contacts
                int count = MatchingContactsAsArrayList.size();

                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    //for each Matching Contacts row in the recyclerview
                    LinearLayout itemLayout = (LinearLayout) recyclerView.getChildAt(i); // Find by under LinearLayout
                    //for each Matching Contacts checkbox
                    CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxContact);
                    //get other data related to the selected contact - name and number
                    SelectPhoneContact data = (SelectPhoneContact) checkbox.getTag();

                    //if that checkbox is checked, then get the phone number
                    if (checkbox.isChecked()) {

                        Toast.makeText(NewContact.this, data.getPhone(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

The error is on line 303, which is:

```
SelectPhoneContact data = (SelectPhoneContact) checkbox.getTag();
```

Comment: Where and how are you setting the tag?

Comment: In the `onBindViewHolder` on my `recyclerViewAdapter` I have  `CheckBox check = ((MatchingContact) viewHolder).check; ` and `check.setTag(position);`, which I need. Is it just the case of setting another tag there like `check.setTag(data);` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want two tags, use [the two-parameter `setTag()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(int,%20java.lang.Object)) and [the one-parameter `getTag()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTag(int)).

Or, create a single object that holds your data (the view-holder pattern) and associate that with the tag, using the methods that you are using.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're setting an `Integer` type object as your checkbox's tag object, and trying to cast it to `SelectPhoneContact` object in your `OnClickListener`.

Answer (score 0):

`checkbox.getTag()` returns data in `Integer` format and you are trying to cast it into `SelectPhoneContact` that's why you are getting [`ClassCastException`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ClassCastException.html) because you have attempted to cast an object to a subclass of which it is not an instance.